# Pass the array from one fuction's callback to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass from one function's callback array to another function?

```js
loadData: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: utils.createUrl('api', 'dashboard-read'),
      async: true,
      callback: function(opts, success, response) {

        if (success) {
          var output = App.decodeHttpResp(response.responseText);
          const data = output.data;
          me.hrer
          let myArr = [];
          data.map((date) =>
            myArr = Object.keys(date).filter(key => key != 'DATE'));
        }
      }
    });
  },



  loadChart: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.apply(me, {
          items: [{ ....

              }
```

Here I want to pass myArr to loadChart in extjs. Possible. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: google ES6 import export

Comment: `this.loadChart(myArr)` and `loadChart: function(array) {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define loadChart like this :

```
loadChart: function(array) {
```

And call it this way :

```
let myArr = [];
//...
this.loadChart(myArr)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is correct. But here the problem is since callback of loaddata is executing after the loadchart function I couldn't get the output. Is there anyway to make the callback function to perform before loadchart function

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you call `loadChart` from within the callback function, how can `loadChart` run _before_ the callback?